# Laravel custom field name in form request validation

Tags: laravel-5

I have a form fields in the view as:-

```
<input type="email" name="user[email]">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="designation">
```

While submitting this post request, I have a rule defined as:-

**app\Http\Requests\StaffEditRequest.php**

```
$rule['user.email'] = 'email|unique:users';
```

However, when Laravel tries to validate the request it queries the database as if there is a field name `user.email` in the `users` table.

How do I customize the field name so that I can tell Laravel that I am looking for email field in the users table and not `user.email`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the column in in unique parameter. Do like following:

```
$rule['user.email'] = 'email|unique:users,email';
```

Ref: [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique)